# For all $f$ in a totally ordered field, $0\,{\preceq}\,f*f$

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, order-theory, ordered-fields

Let $(F,+,*,{\preceq})$ be a totally ordered field.

Then ${\forall}f\,{\in}\,F:0_F\,{\preceq}\,f*f$.

It's obvious from the definition of total ordering on a field that this applies to $f:0_F\,{\preceq}\,f$. Since $0_F\,{\preceq}\,a\,{\land}\,0_F\,{\preceq}\,b{\implies}0_F\,{\preceq}\,a*b$, we know that $f^2$ must succeed $0_F$.

What about the cases $f:f\,{\preceq}\,0_F\,{\land}\,f\,{\neq}\,0_F$? How do we prove the theorem for them?

Comment: That's because you consider $-f$ whose square is the same as $f$.

Comment: Why does $(-f)*(-f)=f*f$

Comment: @asdasdfsss $(-1)^2 - 1^2 = (-1 -1)(-1 +1) = 0$.